# Why are Objective-C blocks not handled through pointers as are other Objective-C objects?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, objective-c-blocks

In code that uses blocks, you frequently see declarations such as:

```
typedef void(^Thunk)(void);
Thunk block1 = ^{NSLog(@"%d %p",i, &i);};
```

instead of

```
typedef void(^Thunk)(void);
Thunk *block1 = ^{NSLog(@"%d %p",i, &i);};
```

Blocks seem to be the only Objective-C object that is handled directly, instead of through a pointer. Why is this? Aren't they regular objects?

Comment: I think they are pointers, it's just that the syntax is based on C's weird pointer to function syntax.

Comment: @nielsbot Wrong. C's pointer to function syntax definitely uses the asterisk in it: `void (*func)(void);`.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII nielsbot probably meant that the syntaxes are similar, at least that's what I understood.

Comment: Yes, exactly. Pointer to function "thePtr": `void(*thePtr)(...)`, thus pointer to block "theBlock": `void(^theBlock)(...)`. So, it's a pointer already, but doesn't use the "*". Also, see Rob's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the [block implementation](http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/compiler-rt/trunk/lib/BlocksRuntime/Block_private.h), you will see that blocks *are* ObjC objects.
If you inspect a stack block (like in your example), you'll see something like this:

```
(lldb) po myBlock
<__NSStackBlock__: 0xbfffc940>
```

And you will notice in the [public header](http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/compiler-rt/trunk/lib/BlocksRuntime/Block.h) `_Block_copy()` and `_Block_release()` take `void*` arguments.

The non-pointeryness is just syntactic sugar the compiler provides to shield you from the dirty bits of blocks.

Comment: from the LLVM documentation that describes the block syntax http://clang.llvm.org/docs/BlockLanguageSpec.html#id4: A variable with Block type is declared using function pointer style notation substituting ^ for *. The type_expression extends C expression parsing to accommodate Block reference declarations as it accommodates function pointer declarations.
typedef int (*pointerToFunctionThatReturnsIntWithCharArg)(char);
pointerToFunctionThatReturnsIntWithCharArg functionPointer;
^ pointerToFunctionThatReturnsIntWithCharArg (float x) { return functionPointer; }

Answer (score 7):

If you're wondering about the missing `*`: In your example you typedef'd the block which is hiding the syntax. You can do this with other objects as well:

```
typedef NSNumber *Number;
Number foo = @42;
```

When assigning a block to a variable that's actually assigning a pointer.

Blocks are a bit like C arrays: Block literals are structures created by the compiler. Block variables are pointers behind the scenes.

Answer (score 5):

You're not handling a block “directly”.  You're handling it indirectly.

The syntax `void (^)(void)` declares a pointer to a block.  There is no syntax for type “block”; there is only syntax for type “pointer to a block”.

From the [Language Specification for Blocks](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/BlockLanguageSpec.html#the-block-type):

> The abstract declarator,
>
> ```
> int (^)(char, float)
> ```
>
> describes a reference to a Block that, when invoked, takes two parameters, the first of type char and the second of type float, and returns a value of type int. The Block referenced is of opaque data that may reside in automatic (stack) memory, global memory, or heap memory.

The relevant bit is “describes a **reference** to a Block”.

The specification isn't entirely consistent, since (for example) it refers to a “variable with Block type” and “Block variable declarations“.  But in fact a variable **always** holds a reference (pointer) to a block, and **never** holds a block directly as its value.

Answer (score 1):

Blocks are a C extension. You can use blocks in C (where the extension is supported).

Apple just happens to have implemented blocks using ObjC types.

Implementation details: Blocks are one of the few ObjC types which may be allocated on the stack using clang. Normally, this is not an option because almost every API expects that an `objc_object` is a heap allocation which supports reference counting.